# javascript, When right div is hidden left div has to be 100% width

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html

FIXED

fixed it by editing mplungjan's code to this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#foo").on("click",function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) $('#checked-a').show('fast',function() {
            $('#checked-b').css("width","60%");
            $('#checked-a').css("width","40%");
        }) ;
        else $('#checked-a').show('fast',function(){
           $('#checked-b').css("width","100%").show();         
           $('#checked-a').css("width","0%").hide();

        });
    });
});
```

i would like to have the left div to be 100% (current 60%) when right div (40%) is hidden.

screenshot with checked checkbox: 
[image: with checkbox checked (default)]

screenshot with unchecked checkbox:
[image: unchecked (div is hidden)]

now i would like to make the left div cover the whole width of the page (100%).

here is my code:

javascript:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    ($('input[name = "foo"]').is(':checked'))
    $('#checked-a').slideDown('fast');
    });
  </script>
```

div:

```
    <div class="content2" id="checked-a">
    <%= yield %>
</div>
```

html input:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="foo" value="1" onclick="$(this).is(':checked') && $('#checked-a').slideDown('fast') || $('#checked-a').slideUp('fast');"/>
```

hope someone could help :)

Comment: 1) create a function instead of inline. 2) add `$("#content1").css("width","100%")` where needed

Comment: Can you give an example of how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you mean this? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/5rdXh/)

```
$(function() {
    $("#foo").on("click",function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) $('#checked-a').slideDown('fast',function() {
            $('#checked-a').css("width","40%");
            $('#checked-b').show();
        }) ;
        else $('#checked-b').slideUp('fast',function(){
           $('#checked-a').css("width","100%");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This does not work the right div will get 100% instead of the left div. can you edit my code so it works?