# How to hide/show div with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html, show-hide

I want to achieve hide/show with div's in html but in this way.

Here is my html:

```
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="middle"> 
<input type="button" id="button"/>
</div>
<div id="right"></div>
```

And this is my css:

```
body 
{ 
 height: 100%; 
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0 ;
 border: 0 none;
}
#left
{
background-color:#EEEEEE;
height:570px;
width:73.9%;
float:left;
}
#center
{
background-color:#D4EAE4;
color:#535353;
height:570px;
width:15.25%;
float:left;
margin:0;
}
#right
{
background-color:#D4EAE4;
 float:left;
 width:11%;
 height:570px;
 margin:0;
}
```

I want to do that when I click button on div `center` to hide div `right` and to expand div`left` for the size of the div `right` and then move div `center` all the way to the right. I want to hide/show them with horizontal animation, such as from left to right or right to left.
Playing with the words can be tricky so I made a little pictures so you can actually see what am I talking about:

Start phase:
[image: Start phase]

And end phase:
[image]

Comment: And http://whathaveyoutried.com?

Comment: You could easily hide that div calling a function like `function hideDiv(id, state) { document.getElementById(id).style.display = state; }`. Now, onto the left div to move to get the rest of the space, wouldn't a `width:100%` do it?

Comment: @antyrat I tried only show/hide which I couldn't set properly as I am new to javascript so I just put detailed question in here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see a working demo here... http://jsfiddle.net/miqdad/3WDbz/

or you can see other demo which increment width of first div here .. http://jsfiddle.net/miqdad/3WDbz/1/

Comment: i was just creating that type of fiddle, thank God refresh this question see it is done )

Comment: One question, what if I have it other way around. To start it as div `right` hidden and then on button I can show it? How to change the code? Do I need to change css too?

Answer (score 1):

I had almost the same question a couple of days ago and maybe it helps you too.
this example uses a checkbox to hide the div. and make the other div 100% width.

[javascript, When right div is hidden left div has to be 100% width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015286/javascript-when-right-div-is-hidden-left-div-has-to-be-100-width).

the javascript code from the example:

```
$(function() {
    $("#foo").on("click",function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) $('#checked-a').show('fast',function() {
            $('#checked-b').css("width","60%");
            $('#checked-a').css("width","40%");
        }) ;
        else $('#checked-a').show('fast',function(){
           $('#checked-b').css("width","100%").show();         
           $('#checked-a').css("width","0%").hide();

        });
    });
});
```

and an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/5rdXh/

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the best ways to hide a div element using JavaScript:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
      function hideDiv() {
      document.getElementById("myP2").style.visibility = "hidden";
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onClick="hideDiv()">Hide</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p id="myP2">Hello world!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementing with JQuery is easy. Have a look at this JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/q39wv/2/

(To all: Normally I wouldn't put only a JSFiddle link here, but this time I think it's worth showing the OP how the whole thing works, with some adjustments to his HTML and CSS).

A Javascript-only solution would be much more difficult to implement.