# Javascript, Function when checkbox unchecked div is hidden, remember on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I still have the problem and i don't know how to fix it. thanks to the answers given i hava an idea of how it looks, but i don't know how to make it working.

---

I have a problem with my javascript checkbox code.

I have a function to hide a div (my other post: [javascript, When right div is hidden left div has to be 100% width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015286/javascript-when-right-div-is-hidden-left-div-has-to-be-100-width))

But when i refresh the page the checkbox will be checked again, i read something about cookies but i don't know how to implement this.

My javascript code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#foo").on("click",function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) $('#checked-a').show('fast',function() {
            $('#checked-b').css("width","60%");
            $('#checked-a').css("width","38%");
        }) ;
        else $('#checked-a').show('fast',function(){
           $('#checked-b').css("width","100%").show();         
           $('#checked-a').css("width","0%").hide();

        });
    });
});
```

My html code for the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="foo" id="foo" />
```

My Div's:

```
    <div class="content1" id="checked-b">
    <%= button_to "Zoek", search_index_path, :method => :get, :class => 'contentlinks' %>
    <%= button_to "Print", root_url, :class => 'contentlinks' %>
    <%= button_to "Edit", root_url, :class => 'contentlinks' %>
    <%= button_to "Add", root_url, :class => 'contentlinks' %>
<br>    

<div class="spacing">
    <%= yield %>
</div>

</div>


<div class="content2" id="checked-a">
```

Thanks.

Comment: I still can't figure out how to fix this. i tried te code from the second anser but i does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't want the checkbox to be checked by default use

```
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" id="foo" />
```

instead of

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="foo" id="foo" />
```

If you want to check the status of the checkbox when the page first loads, add this bit of JavaScript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($("#foo").is(':checked')){
        $('#checked-b').css("width","60%");
        $('#checked-a').css("width","38%");
    } else {
        $('#checked-b').css("width","100%");
        $('#checked-a').css("width","0%").hide();
    }
});
```

If you want the user's browser to remember if the status of the "foo" checkbox each time the user visits your site, you likely will need to read up on cookies. [Here's a guide for JS Cookies at w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

---

**Edit**

I'll make no claims that this works because I haven't tried it, nor have I ever used cookies myself (but I did re-discover that Google has the answers to basically everything. It's really quite easy when you give it half an effort)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (get_cookie( "fooIsChecked" ) == 1){
        $('#foo').prop("checked", true);
        $('#checked-b').css("width","60%");
        $('#checked-a').css("width","38%");
    } else {
        $('#foo').prop("checked", false);
        $('#checked-b').css("width","100%");
        $('#checked-a').css("width","0%").hide();
    }
    $("#foo").on("click",function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')){
            set_cookie( "fooIsChecked", "1", 30 );
            $('#checked-a').show('fast',function() {
                $('#checked-b').css("width","60%");
                $('#checked-a').css("width","38%");
            }) ;
        } else {
            set_cookie( "fooIsChecked", "0", 30 );
            $('#checked-a').show('fast',function(){
                $('#checked-b').css("width","100%").show();         
                $('#checked-a').css("width","0%").hide();
            });
        }
    });
});

function set_cookie ( cookie_name, cookie_value, lifespan_in_days, valid_domain ){
    var domain_string = valid_domain ? ("; domain=" + valid_domain) : '' ;
    document.cookie = cookie_name +
        "=" + encodeURIComponent( cookie_value ) +
        "; max-age=" + 60 * 60 * 24 * lifespan_in_days +
        "; path=/" + domain_string;
}

function get_cookie ( cookie_name ){
    var cookie_string = document.cookie;
    if (cookie_string.length != 0) {
        var cookie_value = cookie_string.match (
            '(^|;)[\s]*' + cookie_name + '=([^;]*)' );
        return decodeURIComponent ( cookie_value[2] ) ;
    }
    return '' ;
}
```

Code modified from [The Site Wizard](http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/cookies.shtml)

Comment: that's my whole problem. i don't know how to implement that cookie code into my existing code. and i want the checkbox to be checked by default, so i don't change that.

Comment: Google is your friend. https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+how+to+use+cookies

Answer (score 1):

After refresh your page, your jQuery piece isn't executed since it depends on 'click' action.

Web browser would see checked="checked", and it would check your checkbox.

You should use a variable to help web browser remember your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement this using a hash in your url.

Please see this code:

```
// set the state of your div as hash
window.location.hash = "#hide-div"; 

// now on document ready check the following
if(window.location.hash == '#hide-div') {
    // do something to hide your div and uncheck your checkbox
} 

if(window.location.hash == '#show-div') {
    // do something to show your div and ucheck your checkbox
}
```

And also the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

Edit:

```
$(function() {
    $("#foo").on("click",function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) $('#checked-a').show('fast',function() {
            $('#checked-b').css("width","60%");
            $('#checked-a').css("width","38%");
            window.location.hash = "#show-div"; 
        }) ;
        else $('#checked-a').show('fast',function(){
           $('#checked-b').css("width","100%").show();         
           $('#checked-a').css("width","0%").hide();
           window.location.hash = "#hide-div";     
        });
    });

    if(window.location.hash == '#show-div') {
        // do something to hide your div and uncheck your checkbox
        $("#foo").trigger('click');
    } 
});
```

Comment: How do i implement this to my code? i'm a beginner to javascript so i don't know how to specify the #hide-div and #show-div in my existing code.

Comment: See my updated answer. I've not tested it, pelase consider it as pseudo code and remember, we're to help you, not to code for you.

Comment: i know but know i know how to implement it for example. that was my question thanks, i will try your code.

Comment: hmm it does not work. but where do you specify the #show-div? because i think this is linking to no function.

Comment: Please read the documentation I provided. This should change your URL.

Comment: #foo is my actual id, so that's the name i use. do i have to change the #show-div and #hide div? to any other names.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't have anything todo with the ID property.

Comment: but why isn't it working, what do i have to change. sorry for being a jerk.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13000/discussion-between-kees-sonnema-and-julian-hollmann)